# Compiler / Assembler (Toolchain) for PIC micro's using Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: pic, embedded, linux, compiler

I used to use Hi-Tide from Hi-Tech before they were purchased by MPLab. In my opinion it was great. I wrote the C code, selected the processor and out popped a hex file.
I've now migrated to Ubuntu 11.04 and need to be able to compile/assemble C code for Pic micros. I've been trying to bend SDCC to my will for some time with little success, and apparently their support of PIC is still in development (according to the man).
I tried using Hi-Tide 3 for Linux, but had no success even launching the IDE.
I am not looking for an IDE or anything like that. Just need a solid, sane, relatively easy toolchain that doesnt need to be poked and prodded at every step to produce a functioning hex file for PIC's.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
I'm near the points where I might as well just start writting my own hex files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MPLAB-X](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/mplab/X_Beta/installer.html) is a full IDE and collection of toolchains for all the PIC micros.

The IDE itself isn't that wonderful, being written in JAVA, bit it's tolerable.

Personally I use the toolchains that come with MPLAB-X but use Anjuta for my IDE.

Comment: I have tried running MPLAB-x under wine (with the Hi-Tech C compiler) and am having no success. Anjuta looks good but i'm not looking for an IDE right now. Also doesn't look like it's geared for embedded systems. Just need to compile/assemble/link into Intel Hex.

Comment: You don't need wine.  MPLAB-X is in Java, and there are native Linux versions of the toolchains.  Check the "Select Platform:" drop-down on the page I link to in my answer.

Comment: I apologize. I tried MPLAB 8.76 under wine, not MPLAB-X. Will try when available.  As an update, I was finally able to get SDCC to compile/link/assemble with minimal warnings. Have not tried yet.

Comment: SDCC's PIC support is still quite basic.  I used to use it on PIC16 devices.

Comment: MPLAB-x works 100 times better then 8.76. And has a much better IDE interface I think. Could not get it to function with my cheap crap ass JDM programmer, although that was not a shock. PICKIT2 is on the way. Thanks for the help, saved me a bunch of frustration.